# Magento 2 Catalog Rule Exclude Category Condition

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I need to create a catalog rule that applies a 10% discount on all products of certain brands and seasons that are not in a specific category.

I have 3 products:

1. price=100; brand=X; season=Y; categoryIds=3,4,5
2. price=100; brand=X; season=Y; categoryIds=3,4,6
3. price=100; brand=X; season=Y; categoryIds=3,4,7

How I created the rule:

-Info

```
Name=test
Status=Enabled
Websites=All selected
Customer Groups=All selected
From Date=Today date
Priority=0
```

-Conditions

```
If [ALL] of these conditions are [TRUE]:
    Brand [IS] X (selected from dropdown list)
    Season [IS] Y (selected from dropdown list)
    Category [IS NOT/NOT CONTAINS/IS NOT ONE OF] 5 (I tried 
with this 3 options)
```

-Actions

```
Apply=first option selected
discount=10
```

Expected Result:

1. new price=100;
2. new price=90;
3. new price=90;

Actual Result:

1. new price=90;
2. new price=90;
3. new price=90;

I tried with a lot of combination but there is no way to exclude a product of a specific category.

Hope for help,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Make sure that all simple products associated with the configurable product are in the same categories.